# trabalhando com decimal {5,2} rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

criei a minha primeira API em Rails, e estou usando um modelo simples com para criar um Crud básico, consegui colocar minha aplicação para funcionar criei o metódo GET bonitinho retornado 200, só que no meu POST está retornando o seguite erro em meu DHC

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou suspeitando que tenho que fazer algum tipo de validação para ele identificar os meus campos decimais pois esse erro apareceu quando eu defini os campos monetários {5,2} segue o meu arquivo de migração.

```
class CreateCnhs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
   def change
     create_table :cnhs do |t|
     t.string :Descricao, :limit => 80
     t.decimal :valorAula, precision: 5, scale: 2
     t.decimal :ValorReteste, precision: 5, scale: 2
     t.decimal :ValorAulaExtra, precision: 5, scale: 2
     t.timestamps
   end
end
```

o erro da na linha 15 de  minha control ler onde eu recebo a validação de meus parâmetros, segue a minha controller.

```
module Api
module V1
    class CnhController < ApplicationController
        def index
            cnhs = Cnh.order('created_at DESC');
            render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Solicitação atendida com sucesso!', Result:cnhs}, status: :ok
        end

        def show
            cnhs = Cnh.find(params[:id])
            render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Loaded articles', data:cnhs}, status: :ok
        end

        def create
            cnhs = Cnh.new(cnh_params)
            if cnhs.save
                render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Saved articles', data:cnhs}, status: :ok
            else
                render json: {status: 'ERROR', message: 'Article not saved', data:article.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        end

        def destroy
            cnhs = Cnh.find(params[:id])
            cnhs.destroy
            render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Deleted articles', data:cnhs}, status: :ok
        end

        def update
            cnhs = Cnh.find(params[:id])
            if cnhs.update_attributes(cnh_params)
                render json: {status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'Updated articles', data:cnhs}, status: :ok
            else
                render json: {status: 'ERROR', message: 'Article not saved', data:article.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        end

        private 
        def cnh_params
            params.permit(:Descricao, :ValorAula, :ValorAulaExtra, :ValorReteste)
        end
    end
end
```

pelo o que eu percebo ele está tentando fazer algum tipo de validação com os campos decimais com limite nas casas {5,2}, pois fiz um teste com uma migração onde não coloco limitação de campos e funciona perfeito o meu POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema não tem nada a ver com os decimais, e sim com a nomenclatura dos campos.

Seu modelo não contempla `ValorAula`, e sim, como mostrado no arquivo de migração, `valorAula`.

O `ActionController::Parameters#permit` é case-sensitive, portanto ao fazer os strong parameters, use:

```
params.permit(:Descricao, :valorAula, :ValorAulaExtra, :ValorReteste)
```

Outra coisa, em Rails é comum adotar como convenção a nomenclatura de colunas usando snake case, dessa forma:

```
descricao
valor_aula
valor_aula_extra
valor_reteste
```

Considere a mudança da capitalização, evitaria esse tipo de erro que você obteve.

Seguindo as convenções do Rails, você será produtivo. Isso se deve ao Convention over Configuration.

Comment: Show Obrigado pela a aula.